# Dynamically populate and parse JSON in REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest, automation, restsharp

How to dynamically populate JSON request and send to REST API with each barcode, serial_number values as automation having dynamic content data of `barcode` **value** and `serial_number` **value** which is source from a Oracle DB table?

```
barcode value: ["324433435343413","23432444354334433","88634354334434",....]
serial_number value: ["2999","2332","7876",....]
```

JSON Payload Request to send to REST API:

```
{
  "selectType": "library",
  "num": "0",
  "size": "15",
  "title": "RISE",
  "contentField": [
    {
      "key": "barcode",
      "value": {value}  
    },
    {
      "key": "serial_number",
      "value": {value} 
    }
  ]
}
```

Dynamically read the two values from Oracle DB/another JSON file as test data and prepare above JSON Payload request and has to send to Rest API. There are 5000+ product barcode, serial_num values exists has to fetch/read  from DB and prepare Payload with each value and send to API.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to create class Request (Json.NET will made class -> JSON transformation for you) of the JSON and then populate ContentFileld with needed array... Question might need to be clarified first

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a foreach to dynamically generate for each contentField

Answer (score 0):

I would build a JsonRequest model class like so:

```
class JsonRequest
{
    public string SelectType { get; set; }
    public string Num { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // <serialNumber, Barcode> Assuming this data is linked and SerialNumber is unquie.
    public Dictionary<string, string> ContentField { get; set; }
}
```

You may want to change ContentField to a list of ContentField. If a dictionary doesn't give you what you want.

```
class ContentField
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

And then use:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonRequest);
```

To Serialize to a Json string and send it.

Comment: Dynamically how can I build Json string with dynamic barcode,serial num values and parse to send to API. consider dataset has 5K or 6K values to process each run.

Comment: pls provide complete sample